# How to count the number of times a while loop is executed in one second

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a python infinite loop and I need to count how many time this loop is executive in one second, or better how many number have count in one second.

EDIT : my code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import uuid
import random
import time

import itertools, sys

spinner = itertools.cycle(['-', '/', '|', '\\'])

while(1):
   try:
      entropy = str(uuid.uuid4()) \
              + str(random.randrange(2**255)) \
              + str(int(time.time() * 1000000))


      sys.stdout.write(spinner.next())
      sys.stdout.flush()
      sys.stdout.write('\b')

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print "\nKeyboard Break !\n"
      raise SystemExit

   except Exception as inst:
      print type(inst)
      print inst
```

Answer (score 0):

Use time counter:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
```

Increment loops and calculate now time - start time and when  get one second print counter, clear counter and assignment now to start time

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't go out from the while, and I want to see a counter during the exec

Comment: So, use print:
`if now - start_time == one_second:
    print loops
    loops = 0
    start_time = now`

Comment: Great ! :-) Thank you